# PHPExcel not saving my new sheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel for create new sheet for an existing excel file with 3 sheets.

```
$newWorkSheet = new PHPExcel_Worksheet($objPHPExcel, 'filter');
$this->objPHPExcel->addSheet($newWorkSheet);
```

After calling `$this->objPHPExcel->getSheetCount()` it prints 4.
But when I see the current excel file, there is not any new sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting the save part..

example..

```
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

Further Example in the official docs

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 1):

This is only creating an in-memory instance of the sheet.  It will need to be written to disk.